# Extra Space Added to the Image After React Import

Tags: html, css, reactjs

As you can see in the screenshot, some unintended space was added to the top and right of the icons while the original images are square and centered. What might be the problem and how could I fix it?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Here are the code samples:

```html
<div className="toolbarIcon settings">
  <img src={settings} alt="Settings" />
</div>
<div className="toolbarIcon file">
  <img src={file} alt="File" />
</div>
<div className="toolbarIcon share">
  <img src={share} alt="Share" />
</div>
```

```css
.toolbarIcon {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 18px;
  margin: 7px 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toolbarIcon:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 9px;
}

.toolbarIcon img {
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  padding: 8.5px;
}
```

Comment: it looks fine to me, if you inspect element blue is your element area, green is padding and orange for margin, i'm not see any extra space in your screenshoot.

Comment: You can see that the blue areas to the four directions are not even, while they were in the original image.

Comment: Don't mistake the image not being centered within it's 36x36 size for extra padding being added by React. Double check the image in a separate editor to be sure.